# Split the Datetime into Year and Month column in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

**How can we split the Datetime values to Year and month and need to split the columns year
(2017_year, 2018_year so on...) and values under the year column should get month of respective year?**

Example data:

```
call time            area    age
2017-12-12 19:38:00  Rural   28
2018-01-12 22:05:00  Rural   50
2018-02-12 22:33:00  Rural   76
2019-01-12 22:37:00  Urban   45
2020-02-13 00:26:00  Urban   52
```

Required Output:

```
call time            area    age   Year_2017  Year_2018
2017-12-12 19:38:00  Rural   28      jan          jan
2018-01-12 22:05:00  Rural   50      Feb          Feb 
2018-02-12 22:33:00  Rural   76      mar          mar
2019-01-12 22:37:00  Urban   45      Apr          Apr
2020-02-13 00:26:00  Urban   52      may          may
```

Comment: Your required output seems wrong. Row two should be Jan?? Why is both columns filled even if the date is e.g. 2017?

Comment: I'm so sorry for that, actually I written manually as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need generate years and month from `call time` datetimes, so output is different:

Explanation - First generate column of months by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), then convert years to index with `append=True` for `MultiIndex`, so possible reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last add to original:

```
df1 = (df.assign(m = df['call time'].dt.strftime('%b'))
         .set_index(df['call time'].dt.year, append=True)['m']
         .unstack()
         .add_prefix('Year_'))
print (df1)
call time Year_2017 Year_2018 Year_2019 Year_2020
0               Dec       NaN       NaN       NaN
1               NaN       Jan       NaN       NaN
2               NaN       Feb       NaN       NaN
3               NaN       NaN       Jan       NaN
4               NaN       NaN       NaN       Feb


df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
            call time   area  age Year_2017 Year_2018 Year_2019 Year_2020
0 2017-12-12 19:38:00  Rural   28       Dec       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 2018-01-12 22:05:00  Rural   50       NaN       Jan       NaN       NaN
2 2018-02-12 22:33:00  Rural   76       NaN       Feb       NaN       NaN
3 2019-01-12 22:37:00  Urban   45       NaN       NaN       Jan       NaN
4 2020-02-13 00:26:00  Urban   52       NaN       NaN       NaN       Feb
```

Comment: Thanks @jezral and Why we need to set the index call time

Comment: @manojkumar - Because is added `year`s to `index`, so is possible use `unstack` for convert years to columns.